# How to write a reasonable mechanism for the reaction of alcohols to synthase ketone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

In the section of reactions of alcohols in my textbook, there are no mechanisms or explanation for this reaction:
[image]
I am interested in Jones Oxidation particularly. I researched a little bit on internet but can't find a satisfying mechanism for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Going to vary depending on which oxidant you choose

Comment: I noticed later the fact you've mentioned and edited the question.

Comment: Did you try googling it? Here you go: (http://www.name-reaction.com/jones-oxidation). Note that the key step is an E2 elimination across the C-O bond: H-C-O-LG --> C=O where LG is the chromium leaving group.

Comment: but then with Jones oxidation, you form chromic acid isn't it? I could write a simple mechanism if it was basic oxidation. For that try checking the linked posted by @electronpusher

Comment: Thanks @electronpusher , in the link, there is what i want. But, i can't get the basic version that xavier_fakerat mentioned.

Comment: see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43283/mechanism-for-oxidation-of-primary-alcohols-to-carboxylic-acids